# Web Service for Drug interactions

Tags: .net, c#, web-services, web-apis

Can anyone please suggest a free open source web service/web API that can be used for retrieving drug-drug interactions which would be compatible for a .Net application?

Comment: Thanks Franck but that didn't help.  I am looking for a web service or a web api that I can call from my program to retrieve the drug-drug interactions.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. According to your last comment, that's e.g. the programming language, features it should provide, and several other things.

Comment: @user3612390 yes the other did ask for a web service too, there is no answer providing one though as nobody here seems to be aware of any :)